# how do i change the value of os.path.expanduser("~") in python?

Tags: python, python-idle

hi i am having trouble in running python IDLE.

once i have installed EMACS and uninstalled it, whenever i try to run python IDLE it gives me:

Warning: os.path.expanduser("~") points to
C:\Program Files\Emacs\,
but the path does not exist

the IDLE does work, but i can't launch IDLE by simply clicking on "open with IDLE".
i guess i need to change the path of os.path.expanduser to fix this error?
but i can't find it.
where should i look for and which path does it originally point?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to the doc,

> On Windows, HOME and USERPROFILE will be used if set, otherwise a
>   combination of HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE will be used. An initial ~user
>   is handled by stripping the last directory component from the created
>   user path derived above.

You can try run 'set' in command prompt to see if these two environment variables are set or not. If yes, remove the setting.